# Swift Scroll View with slider and MIDI

Tags: swift, macos, scroll, xcode8, midi

Im using Scroll View to scroll a picture. I'm using a slider 1 - 26 to retrieve CGPoint from an Array for x axis points. Everything behaves as expected and the image is smooth in transition.

I also set up a button that when pressed count from 1 - 26 and loops to retrieve CGPoint from an Array for x axis points. Everything behaves as expected and the image is smooth in transition.

I have also set up MIDI that sends data 1 - 26 based on velocity this is sent to the slider, and the slider moves as expected. I also using MIDI to retrieve CGPoint from an Array for x axis points. Unfortunately although it wants to scroll the following pictures shows what happens you only get to see 4 images as it scrolls and you can tell by the moving slider when they appear

[image: Under Midi Control]

I'm very confident that the Midi is working correctly as i use it all the time to read from arrays. I have also tried triggering the button from Midi a kind of virtual press. This works as expected but shows the same as triggering directly from midi. It seems as though everything is fine as long as the scroll originates from a IB component.

Under Midi control the scroll bar also stutters but if i set

```
clipView.wantsLayer = true
```

The picture does not scroll under midi but the scroll bar moves as expected. Even though the slider and the button work as expected.

I have also tried all the things commented out in the playMidi. As well trying all the different parameters in the IB section.

I am at a point where i really could do with some help please.
Here is my code which hopefully also explains what i have tried.
I have also tried various

```
needsDisplay = true
```

on all views

Xcode 8 Swift3  OSX not iOS

Thank you for you time

```
import Cocoa
import CoreMIDI

class MainWindowController: NSWindowController {
    static var subWindowController: MainWindowController!

    var pointArray:[Double] = [99.00,0.00,40.00,80.00,120.00,160.00,200.00,240.00,280.00,320.00,360.00,400.00,440.00,480.00,520.00,560.00,600.00,640.00,680.00,720.00,760.00,800.00,840.00,880.00,920.00,960.00,1000.00]

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: NSScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var clipView: NSClipView!
    @IBOutlet weak var ImageView: NSImageView!
    @IBOutlet var scrollerBar: NSScroller!
    @IBOutlet weak var sliderControl: NSSlider!

    var myPointer = CGPoint.init(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
    var fromArray:Double = 0.0
    var buttonCount = 0

    override func windowDidLoad() {
        super.windowDidLoad()
        MainWindowController.subWindowController = self // USED for midi

        //Initialize midi client
        var midiClient: MIDIClientRef = 0;
        var inPort:MIDIPortRef = 0;
        var src:MIDIEndpointRef = MIDIGetSource(0);
        MIDIClientCreate("MidiTestClient" as CFString, nil, nil, &midiClient);
        MIDIInputPortCreate(midiClient, "MidiTest_InPort" as CFString, MyMIDIReadProc, nil, &inPort);
        MIDIPortConnectSource(inPort, src, &src);

        //Set paramameters
        scrollerBar.doubleValue = 0.9

        let scrollViewSize = NSSize(width: 287, height: 119)
        scrollView.setFrameSize(scrollViewSize)
        let scrollViewColor = CGColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.9, alpha: 0.5)
        scrollView.wantsLayer = false
        scrollView.layer?.backgroundColor = scrollViewColor
        scrollView.drawsBackground = false

        let clipViewSize = NSSize(width: 1274, height: 88)
        clipView.setFrameSize(clipViewSize)
        let clipViewColor = CGColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.9, alpha: 0.5)
        clipView.wantsLayer = false //If true image freezes but scoller moves with midi
        clipView.layer?.backgroundColor = clipViewColor
        clipView.drawsBackground = false

        let ImageViewSize = NSSize(width: 1274, height: 87)
        ImageView.setFrameSize(ImageViewSize)
        /* let ImageViewColor = CGColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.9, blue: 0.0, alpha: 0.5)
         ImageView.wantsLayer = false
         ImageView.layer?.backgroundColor = ImageViewColor*/

    }//EO Overide


    func playMidi(count:Int){

        //print("MIDi",count)
        let fromCountIndex = count // Gets 1 to 26 from midi

        //Gets double from Array 1 to 26 on Index == 0.0 to 960.0
        fromArray = pointArray[fromCountIndex]

        /*SCROLL BAR THINGS I HAVE TRIED*/
        let scrollerValue = fromArray/960
        scrollerBar.doubleValue = scrollerValue
      /*  scrollerBar.display()
        scrollerBar.isContinuous = true */

        /*CLIP VIEW SCROLL FROM ARRAY TRIGGERED BY MIDI */
        myPointer = CGPoint(x:fromArray,y:0.0)
        clipView.scroll(myPointer)
        /*scrollView.scroll(clipView, to: myPointer)*/

        /*THIS FAKES A BUTTON FIRE BUT STILL SAME PROBLEM*/
        /* let mySelector = #selector(myButton(_:))
         myButton(mySelector as AnyObject)*/

        /* DISPLAY VIEWS I HAVE TRIED*/
        // scrollView.scrollsDynamically = true

        /*MOVES THE SLIDER USING MIDI*/
        sliderControl.integerValue = count

    }//eo playMidi


    @IBAction func myButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        fromArray = pointArray[buttonCount]
        myPointer = CGPoint(x:fromArray,y:0.0)
        clipView.scroll(myPointer)
        buttonCount = buttonCount + 1
        if (buttonCount > 26){buttonCount = 0}
        print("buttonCount",buttonCount)
    }

    @IBAction func mySlider(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        let fromSlider = sender.integerValue * 1
        //Gets double from Array 1 to 26 on Index == 0.0 to 960.0 on array set to 40 when using slider moves scroll bar
        fromArray = pointArray[fromSlider]
        myPointer = CGPoint(x:fromArray,y:0.0)
        clipView.scroll(myPointer)
        print("fromSlider",fromSlider)
    }


}//EnD oF thE wORld
```

Answer (score 0):

Further to my code as above I have not answered the question but instead found a "get around". I'm really not proud of this but it seems to pose a question that maybe someone might help in answering. As the code above using the Scroll View was not working i have instead tried using CAScrollLayer.

The basic setup is as follow. I have a view inside that view I created a Scroll Layer and inside that a layer. Again as above if I use a timer to fire the scroll view everything works perfectly. And again as above if i use Midi then the scroll doesn't happen. So the work around is. The midi 1-26 reads the point value the but instead of trying to send it to the scroll it send it to a transistion variable.

I have a "Run Button" on the interface this would normally work the scrollLayerScroll. It still does this but at an incredible speed. But instead of generation its own transition variable it uses the one created buy the midi function. There is a piece of code that makes sure only a unique number is sent to the point.

This works but really deserves a prize for the worst bit of coding ever.

I think there is something in the way the timer refreshes everything that i need to extract. I hoping someone may still take pity and help

thanks again

here is the revised code Xcode 8 Swift3 OSX not iOS

```
import Cocoa
import CoreMIDI

class MainWindowController: NSWindowController {
    static var subWindowController: MainWindowController!

    var myLayer = CALayer()
    var myPointer = CGPoint.init(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
    var fromArray:Double = 0.0
    var buttonCount = 0
    var pointArray:[Double] = [99.00,0.00,40.00,80.00,120.00,160.00,200.00,240.00,280.00,320.00,360.00,400.00,440.00,480.00,520.00,560.00,600.00,640.00,680.00,720.00,760.00,800.00,840.00,880.00,920.00,960.00,1000.00]

    @IBOutlet weak var myCustomView: NSView!

    var translation: CGFloat = 0.0
    var newTranslation:CGFloat = 0.0
    var comp6:CGFloat = 0.0
    var comp6a:CGFloat = 0.0


    var scrollLayer : CAScrollLayer = {
        let scrollLayer = CAScrollLayer() // 8
        scrollLayer.bounds = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 150.0, height: 200.0) // 9
        scrollLayer.position = CGPoint(x: 300/2, y: 180/2) // 10 //not sure about this
        scrollLayer.borderColor = CGColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 0.8)
        scrollLayer.borderWidth = 5.0 // 12
        scrollLayer.scrollMode = kCAScrollHorizontally // 13
        return scrollLayer
    }()

    var scrollTimer = Timer()
    var layer = CALayer()

    override func windowDidLoad() {
        super.windowDidLoad()
        MainWindowController.subWindowController = self // USED for midi

        //Initialize midi client
        var midiClient: MIDIClientRef = 0;
        var inPort:MIDIPortRef = 0;
        var src:MIDIEndpointRef = MIDIGetSource(0);
        MIDIClientCreate("MidiTestClient" as CFString, nil, nil, &midiClient);
        MIDIInputPortCreate(midiClient, "MidiTest_InPort" as CFString, MyMIDIReadProc, nil, &inPort);
        MIDIPortConnectSource(inPort, src, &src);

        //Set up layer
        let img = NSImage(named: "smallSky.png")
        let imageSize = img?.size
        print (imageSize)
        let layer = CALayer()
        layer.bounds = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: (imageSize?.width)!, height: (imageSize?.height)!) // 3
        layer.position = CGPoint(x: (imageSize?.width)!/4, y: (imageSize?.height)!/2) // 4
        layer.contents = img//5


        myCustomView.layer?.addSublayer(scrollLayer)
        scrollLayer.addSublayer(layer)

        myCustomView.layer = scrollLayer
        myCustomView.wantsLayer = true

    }//EO Overide


    @IBAction func runButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        print("run")
        //Sets of timer at very high Speed
        scrollTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.0001, target: self, selector: #selector(MainWindowController.scrollLayerScroll as (MainWindowController) -> () -> ()), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func scrollLayerScroll(){//FIRED START FROM RUN BUTTON
        //Collects data from translation and only sends to newTranslation when number is different
        comp6a = translation
        if (comp6a != comp6){
            newTranslation = translation
            print("newTranslation",newTranslation)
            let newPoint = CGPoint(x: newTranslation,y:0.0)
            scrollLayer.scroll(to: newPoint)

        }
        comp6 = comp6a
    }//eo scrollLayerScroll


    func playMidi(count:Int){

        let fromCountIndex = count // Gets 1 to 26 from midi
        fromArray = pointArray[fromCountIndex]
        translation = CGFloat(fromArray)
    }//eo playMidi

}//EnD oF thE wORld
```